# How to get high quality video source url for videos uploaded on facebook public page using graph api V2.1

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, video

I am trying to get high quality video source url for videos uploaded on public page by admin and normal users.

By using graph api v2.1 I can get all videos uploaded on this page by using
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.1/547830001966077/feed

But when I try to get details of each video by using following method, sometimes it gives error and sometime it works,

For E.g.
v2.1/817476674942956 => Working

But for shared story 
v2.1/10201407437548351 => Not working

Error Details:

```
{
 "error": {
 "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api", 
 "type": "GraphMethodException", 
 "code": 100
 }
}
```

If we load this video in browser, its showing HD option at bottom,
https://www.facebook.com/photo.php?v=10201407437548351

So I would like to know is there any way to get high quality source url for videos for all users from a public page.

Thank you.

Comment: same problem here...

Comment: it's 2021.. but still no answer? :D